# NetBeans freezing when switching between windows

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins, freeze

Im experiencing some REALLY annoying freezing when working on netbeans. It normally happens when I use alt tab to see google chrome or another program. It started happening when I installed some plugins on netbeans. It always freezes for exactly 43 seconds. What should I do to avoid this problem without having to reinstall my netbeans?

EDIT:

My cpu is Vishera Fx 8350 and I have 8gm of RAM. Version 8.0.2

gonna try the profile stuff and see what happens.

Comment: Use a profiler on your NetBeans while its executed and try to spot the problem.

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your computer? What processor does your computer have? Which version of netbeans are you using?